# VBA - How to change Xvalues / Values of a chart object when the range is discontinuous

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a chart to update  and my date are now discontinous (2020 + one variable to add which is in another column of the same row).

I can achieve this manually and I recorded the macro as such (where `I` is an index where I get my data in the `suiviSC` sheet)

```
Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
        "='suiviSC'!$C$" & I + 3 & ":$N$" & I + 3 & ";'suiviSC'!$AA$" & I + 3

Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = _
        "=suiviSC!$C$" & I + 5 & ":$N$" & I + 5 & ";suiviSC!$AA$" & I + 5
```

But when I run my macro, I get a the 1004 error. I tried to comment the last variable and then it works like a charm.

```
Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
    "='suiviSC'!$C$" & I + 3 & ":$N$" & I + 3 '& ";'suiviSC'!$AA$" & I + 3

    Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    "=suiviSC!$C$" & I + 5 & ":$N$" & I + 5 '& ";suiviSC!$AA$" & I + 5
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem (and don't do it manually)?

Comment: Untested, but try using `,` instead of `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since VBA is en-US centric, I'm guessing the `;` is causing the issue.

Try using `,` as the separator instead of `;`.